# Sorting a list in Python without Sort, Index or the IN operator

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am given 2 lists with a variety of names, for example:

```
A = ["Bob", "Joe", "Eric", "Frank", "John", "Matt"]
B = ["Joe", "Bob", "John"]
```

What I need to do is remove the names from list A, that are in list B so that I am left with:

```
A = ["Eric","Frank","Matt"]
```

The problem is I am **not** allowed to use built-in functions such as `sort`, `index` or the `in` operator. Is anyone able to help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at other collection types that may have functions to do this?  (this isn't really sorting)

Comment: Do not try to remove items from the list A, but rather to create a new list.
You start with a empty list lst, Follow word for word list A and for each word check that it is not in list B. If this is the case add it to the list lst.

Comment: This isn't sorting, but filtering. You can achieve this simply with `filt = set(B); C = [element for element in A if element not in filt]`. You *can* perform membership testing without using the syntax in, but is there any reason for this arbitrary constraint? A way would be to substitute the `if element not in filt` with `if not filt.intersection([element])`. There are many more such ways, but I just don't see the point in this exercise. It also makes it too broad since there are too many different answers that satisfy your criteria.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `list.__contains__()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short and sweet:

```
A = list(set(A)-set(B))
```

This works assuming you are only interested in unique entries.

Comment: Sets don't retain order, so what will come out of the difference may not be in the desired output order the OP has stated.

Comment: For this case, it was to work without order so this works perfectly! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Without using `in` you could do something like:

```
C = []

for obj_a in A:
    match = False
    for obj_b in B:
        if obj_a == obj_b:
            match = True
            break
    if not match:
        C.append(obj_a)
```

Now IF you could use `in`that would take only a line:

```
C = [x for x in A if x not in B]
```